# Looking for a way to redirect aspx requests in a Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

We're creating a new Rails-based site, which is going to replace an old .Net site, which has brought about an interesting issue - is there a way I can set up a route in Rails that will redirect all requests to .aspx pages to somewhere in my Rails app? Say, the home page?

I can do simple things like the following to redirect a request to an individual page:

```
get '/page.aspx' => 'home#index'
```

but I'd like to do something like the following:

```
match '/*.aspx' => redirect('/')
```

That rule does actually work, but it works a little too well - all of my requests now get redirected to root, not just the ones for aspx pages, so is there a better a way to define that aspx matching rule?

Comment: You might try :format => :aspx.  You may need to register a mime type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
scope :format => true, :constraints => { :format => 'aspx' } do
  get '/*x' => redirect('/')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just setup a `before_filter` in the application controller :

```
def ApplicationController <  ActionController::Base
  before_filter :redirect_aspx

  private

  def redirect_aspx
    redirect_to "/", status: :moved_permanently if params[:format] == 'aspx'
  end
end
```